# AWS Signature is Incorrect

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to get a signature for the below code, but the result I am getting is incorrect. When the UTC time is *20190108T053505Z*, I get a result of:

> AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=TEST_ACCESS_KEY/20190108/us-east-1/iotdata/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=**host;x-amz-date**, Signature=**e797617c297b6ae2bed4fb9a5ae3b85b37d7a77d12bb8d0329d6101831376d64**

How can I get the signature to work correctly?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static TextView data;

private AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
Request<?> aws;

String AccessKey = "TEST_ACCESS_KEY";
String SecretKey = "TEST_SECRET_KEY";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fetchdata);

    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKey, SecretKey);
    aws = generateBasicRequest();

    signer.setRegionName("us-east-1");
    signer.setServiceName("iotdata");
    signer.sign(aws, credentials);

    String test = aws.getHeaders().get("X-Amz-Date") + "\n\n" + aws.getHeaders().get("Authorization");

    MainActivity.data.setText(test);
    }

    private Request<?> generateBasicRequest() {
    Request<?> request = new DefaultRequest<Void>("iotdata");

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    request.setHeaders(map);
    request.setResourcePath("/");
    request.setEndpoint(URI.create("https://a37j7zivprtjq5.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/things/thermostat/shadow"));
    request.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.GET);
    return request;
    }
}
```

The correct result I should be getting for the UTC time is:

> AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=TEST_ACCESS_KEY/20190108/us-east-1/iotdata/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=**content-type;host;x-amz-date**, Signature=**f39ccc92a8d60450ceceb32d3bba42fdb06120598d34c5f4f87299abd3d92fb4**

Comment: Trying to understand how you are computing the "correct" value for the Signature. Also, what is happening when you send the request to the server - is it failing with a 403?

Comment: @Bommas I have code which uses node.js and utilizes cryptojs. This version works which is how I computed the correct value. The request doesn't fail. It's just that the AWS4Signer isn't sending the request correctly, and Android Studio won't let me modify it.